# c# LINQ Dynamic select cross join

Tags: c#, linq, select, dynamic

Let's say I have the dictionary `pinDict[N]`. Each element of this dictionary contains different list as string: `Dictionary<int, List<string>> pinDict`. I want to create the select that contains all combinations with dictionaries' entries.

For instance:

```
 var s =
          from d1 in pinDict[0]
          from d2 in pinDict[1]
          from d3 in pinDict[2]
          select new { d1, d2, d3 };
```

It works fine just with predetermined quantity of elements. But I need N elements.

Something like it:

```
   var s =
              from d1 in pinDict[0]
              from d2 in pinDict[1]
              from d3 in pinDict[2]
              .....................
              from d[i-1] in pinDict[i-1]
              from d[i] in pinDict[i]
              select new { d1, d2, d3, ... d[i-1], d[i] };
```

How can I create this select?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely possible in a LINQ query, would a solution using plain C# also suffice?

Comment: do you want all the lists in the dictionary ?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [Dynamically cross-join multiple different-size collections together in Linq (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328235/dynamically-cross-join-multiple-different-size-collections-together-in-linq-c) All you have to do is running this: `var result = GetPermutations(pinDict.Select(d => d.Value));` It gets you the exact result than in the sample code you provided but now you can add more lists to the dictionary without having to update the code.

Comment: derloopkat, thanks for your help. I'll try to get it.